# Vue TypeScript call function on init / created / mounted

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm just starting a Vue TypeScript project 3 hour ago,

Just finishing setting rules eslint and tslint and make the "formatter" does the "rules" want and I'm happy about it,

And now I just want to know how to use created / mounted that will call function when the app / page refresh, because I read the documenttation and try it with no luck.

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <p>{{ name }}</p>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component({
  components: {},
})
export default class App extends Vue {
  name: string = 'hello';
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.test();
  }
  onClick() {
    console.log('clicked');
    this.name = 'Clicked Hello';
  }

  test = (): void => {
    this.name = 'Hello Wrold!';
    console.log('this is test and called');
  };

  mounted = (): void => {
    this.test();
  };

  created = (): void => {
    this.test();
  };
}
</script>
```

I just want to call a function from the start, I know this is very basic, but yeah it's not working for me and I need help for it.

the code from tutorial and answer is work, I just need to re-open the project and start again. But also I use the different answer because less warning for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, you declared data properties that are functions, not methods or hooks. These should not be anonymous functions because they actually need a binded `this`.

```js
@Component
export default class App extends Vue {
   test (): void {
      console.log('Hello')
   }

   created () {
     this.test()
   }

   mounted () {
     this.test()
   }
}
```